# Configurar servidor externo Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, servidor, tomcat

Gostaria de configurar um servidor externo no Tomcat, eu só estou conseguindo criar um servidor localhost, mas tenho uma maquina que criei como servidor e gostaria de utiliza-la para colocar minhas aplicações lá.

Poderiam me ajudar, mandar links uteis ou algo do tipo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dentro da pasta do tomcat/conf se encontra o arquivo server.xml, responsável pela configuração das portas do serviço. Altere a porta na linha `<Connector port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1"   connectionTimeout="20000"    redirectPort="8443" />` e libere a mesma no firewall do sistema operacional.

Comment: Olá Adilson, tudo bem, bom vou tentar e ver se da certo, pois na verdade esse computador seria um servidor, me passaram o nome do servidor ai eu colocaria ele no lugar da porta?

Comment: você criou o servidor ou está usando um servidor pago com tomcat? se você tem acesso a máquina e precisa instalar e configurar o tomcat é preciso liberar a porta no firewall. A porta padrão é a 8080. Caso seja um servidor dedicado ao tomcat, tudo já está configurado.

Comment: é um servidor da empresa, mas preciso conetar ele com o meu eclipse para eu dar deploy na aplicação a unica coisa que me passaram foi "Referente ao server DEV serão esses lnx1281in lnx1282in."

Comment: pra ajudar só com essas informações está difícil. Geralmente o desenvolvedor tem um tomcat local, configurado na sua IDE, após programar a aplicação é feita um deploy no servidor (teste, homologação ou produção).

Comment: Sim, este ambiente que temos é um ambiente de DEV, mas vou buscar ajuda com alguém da empresa, obrigada de qualquer forma Adilson!